# useState hook has stale data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using `useState` hook to set a value from a dropdown to a variable. In my particular instance inside `onDeviceIdChange`, I'm setting `setDeviceId` to `value` which is emitted from an event in the component library I'm using. `value` holds the correct value I'm expecting, however it's not update to `deviceId` immediately.

I've read the various posts related to this issue and the most common solution seems to be passing the variable to the second argument for `useEffect`

So something like this

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchDeviceIds();
    console.log("call back for device id selection", deviceId);
  }, [deviceId]);
```

But that seems to just fire the `fetchDeviceIds` function repeatedly for me and never actually call the change handler. I've tried a few variations with `useEffect` and haven't been able to get the updated value inside `deviceId`

Below was my initial implementation without putting `deviceId` into the second argument of `useEffect`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import { Dropdown, Form, Input } from "semantic-ui-react";

const Example = props => {
  const [deviceId, setDeviceId] = useState("");
  const [hardware, setHardware] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const [versionNum, setVersionNum] = useState("");
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  async function fetchDeviceIds() {
    const url = "/api/hardware";
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "GET"
      });

      if (!response.ok) {  
        setError(response.statusText);
      }

      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);   
      setHardware(data.hardware);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error catch", error);
      console.log("Handle networking errors", error.message);
    }
  }

  const versionUrl = "/api/versionUrl";
  const onDeviceIdChange = async (e, { value }) => {
    console.log("device id value --> ", value);
    setDeviceId(value);
    console.log(deviceId); //this won't update immediately

    if (!deviceId) {
      handleClear();
      return;
    }

      try {
        console.log("calling versionUrl");
        const response = fetch(versionUrl, {
          method: "POST",
          body: JSON.stringify({
            deviceId: deviceId
          }),
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          }
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
          setError(response.statusText);
        }
        const data = response.json();
        console.log(data);
        setVersionNum(data.version_num);
        setIsLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("error catch", error);
        console.log("Handle networking errors", error.message);
      }
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchDeviceIds();
  }, []);

  const handleClear = () => {
    setDeviceId("");
    setVersionNum("");
    setIsLoading(true);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Form.Field required>
        <label style={{ display: "block" }}>device Id</label>
        <Dropdown
          id="deviceId"
          value={deviceId}
          onChange={onDeviceIdChange}
          selection
          fluid
          placeholder="Please select an device ID"
          clearable
          options={hardware.map(device => {
            return {
              text: device.id,
              value: device.id,
              key: device.id
            };
          })}
          style={{ marginTop: ".33", marginBottom: "2em" }}
        />
      </Form.Field>
      <Form.Field>
        <label style={{ display: "block", marginTop: "2em" }}>Version Number</label>

        {isLoading ? (
          <Input
            loading
            iconPosition="left"
            fluid
            placeholder="Choose an device ID..."
            value={versionNum}
          />
        ) : (
          <Input value={versionNum} fluid readOnly />
        )}
      </Form.Field>
    </>
  );
};

export default Example;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setDeviceId(value);
console.log(deviceId); //this won't update immediately because setDeviceId is asynchronous!
```

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value. There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may be batched for performance gains.

React does not update the state and when you console.log you get the previous value

In your case, you can use the `value` for all synchronous actions since it is the new value you are setting OR you can move all the code below setState to inside a `useEffect`

**Update**

From the code below and the [docs](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/)

```
onChange={onDeviceIdChange}
```

The second argument would be an object of the shape `{data: value}`
so your argument `value` will always be undefined!

```
const onDeviceIdChange = async (e, {value}) => {
    console.log("device id value --> ", value);
    console.log("device value from event --> ", e.target.value);
    setDeviceId(value);
  };

useEffect(() => {
    if (!deviceId) {
      handleClear();
      return;
    }
      try {
        console.log("calling versionUrl");
        const response = fetch(versionUrl, {
          method: "POST",
          body: JSON.stringify({
            deviceId: deviceId
          }),
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          }
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
          setError(response.statusText);
        }
        const data = response.json();
        console.log(data);
        setVersionNum(data.version_num);
        setIsLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("error catch", error);
        console.log("Handle networking errors", error.message);
      }
    }
},[deviceId])
```

Comment: so right after `setDeviceId` I have an `if` block that checks if `value` exists and if it doesn't it's calling `handleClear` which seems to fire every time. Thus, it never reaches the try block with my async action

Comment: You are not passing any value to the value!

Comment: it sends `data`

Comment: it does not send `data`, that is undefined when logged in the change handler

Comment: consider not destructuring it and print the value

Comment: @DJ2 updated code above, what is the structure of the second argument ?

Comment: also, what is `e.target.value` it should be also the actual value selected

Comment: `data` emits data for the entire event. The destructure to grab `data.value` is necessary because of semantic ui event handling

Comment: if you are getting value then what was this about ? `I have an if block that checks if value exists and if it doesn't it's calling handleClear which seems to fire every time.`

Comment: the problem with your `if` was you were checking `deviceId` and not `value`; it will work properly if you move it to inside useEffect like above;

Comment: I made a code sandbox with the issue described.. https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-mountain-ixih6. The `deviceId` check is for clearing the dropdown box when the `x` button to the right of the input field. So if there's no `deviceId` then don't make the api call

Comment: if you look in the console, just as I suspected the the handle clear function is getting invoked every time a selection is made so the request to `/deviceId/${deviceId}` is never made

Comment: the async/await synax with the try/catch without any actual async/await keywords was causing an unresolved promise.. see sandbox for solution

Answer (score 0):

`onDeviceIdChange` should look like this:

```
const onDeviceIdChange = async (e, { value }) => {
    // code for validating value etc
    setDeviceId(value);
}
```

and the rest of the code should go into `useEffect` hook that is dependant on `deviceId`:

```
useEffect(fetchId, [deviceId]);
```

Comment: so the rest of the try/catch block that's dependent on `deviceId` should go into `useEffect`?

Comment: @DJ2 you can wrap code for fetching id into a function called `fetchId` and put it into `useEffect`